# Node: name collision on required files

Tags: javascript, node.js

Thanks for reading!!

**The question**

How do I avoid name collision? Is that my problem? Is that the proper term?

**Details**

I'm new to node & javascript and writing an app that talks (tcp on 23) to different types of network devices.

I decide to create a separate js file per device and I `require` them in my `app.js` file.

When I start the app, `apple1` connects but as soon as `banana1` connects, I lose connection with `apple1`.  I do not get a disconnect message from `apple1`.

I suspected that there's some sort of variable name collision because when I change the order of apple connecting last, then banana is the one that I lose connection to. To support my suspicion, within my `banana.js`, where I assign `self = this;`, I changed it to `somethingElse = this`. By doing this, I was able to connect to both devices at the same time.

**app.js**

```
var deviceA = require('./apple.js');
var apple1 = new deviceA({
  ipAddress: "192.168.1.97",
  port: 23
})
apple1.connect();
apple1.on('connect', function(data) {
  console.log('Apple: Device Connected @' + apple1.ipAddress);
})
apple1.on('disconnect', function(data) {
  console.log('Apple: Device Disconnected');
})

var deviceA = require('./banana.js');
var banana1 = new deviceA({
  ipAddress: "192.168.1.97",
  port: 23
})
banana1.connect();
banana1.on('connect', function(data) {
  console.log('Banana: Device Connected @' + banana1.ipAddress);
})
banana1.on('disconnect', function(data) {
  console.log('Banana: Device Disconnected');
})
```

**apple.js**

```
var events = require('events');

var Apple = function(opts) {
  this.ipAddress = opts.ipAddress;
  this.port = opts.port;
};

Apple.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;
module.exports = Apple;

Apple.prototype.connect = function() {
  self = this;
  // telnet to apple
  var net = require('net');
  self.connection = net.createConnection(self.port, self.ipAddress);
  self.connection.setEncoding("UTF8");

  self.connection.on('connect', function(data) {
    self.emit('connect');
  });
  self.connection.on('disconncect', function(data) {
    self.emit('disconnect');
  });
}
```

**banana.js**

```
var events = require('events');

var Banana = function(opts) {
  this.ipAddress = opts.ipAddress;
  this.port = opts.port;
};

Banana.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;
module.exports = Banana;

Banana.prototype.connect = function() {
  self = this;
  // telnet to banana
  var net = require('net');
  self.connection = net.createConnection(self.port, self.ipAddress);
  self.connection.setEncoding("UTF8");

  self.connection.on('connect', function(data) {
    self.emit('connect');
  });
  self.connection.on('disconncect', function(data) {
    self.emit('disconnect');
  });
}
```

Comment: Required files are fetched by file path. (unless they are available in node_modules) So, no such collision is happening. Another thing I can see is that you are duplicating code for both devices. You can create a Device class in javascript and create 2 instances from it.

Comment: Yes, you are missing the `var` declaration for `self`. Use strict mode!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I avoid name collision?

Don't use [(implicit) global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) variables.

> Is that my problem?

Yes. You caused it, and you need to fix it.

> Is that the proper term?

Yes!

> How to fix it?

Don't rename the colliding variable, but [declare it as local using `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

> How to prevent this?

Use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) for all your files, and you'd get an exception on assigning to undeclared global variables.

Comment: Survey says... NUMBER ONE ANSWER!